# My req.session data isn't being global, like when I tried to send it from server by app.get it's showing undefiend - express session

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

thru app.post I got the data from my front end by ajax request. that data I tried to store with session. And I was expecting this would be global. Then I made app.get function, thru witch I wanted to send the data back to front end where I made another ajax request, but I'm getiing undefined. This is the first time I'm working with session, any hint where i'm  going wrong?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');


app.set('view engine', 'pug');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret-key',
  resave : false,
  saveUninitialized:false
}));


const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: '',
    database: 'exdb'
  });


app.post('/reps_ex', (req,res)=>{
  req.session.ex_info = [];
  req.body.name.forEach(element => {
    req.session.ex_info.push(element); 
  });
  res.send('working');
});

app.get('/session_ex', (req,res)=>{
  if(req.session.ex_info){
    res.send(req.session.ex_info);
  }
  else{
    res.send([{name : false}]);
  }
});




app.listen(PORT, () =>{
  console.log('server listening on ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: What does the client request look like?  Can you show that code?  If this is coming from an ajax call, then I would guess that you're not specifying the options correctly to send cookies so the session cookie is not sent and thus is creates a new empty session on every new request.  If it's a pure API call from something other than a browser, then maybe you aren't using a cookieJar appropriately with whatever http library you're using for the request.

Comment: ya it's ajax request, look like this: var ex_started;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/session_ex',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success:function(response){
            if(response[0].name === false){
                ex_started = false;
            }
            else{
                ex_started = response;
                console.log(ex_started);
            }
        },
        complete : function(){
            $( "#mainCard fieldset input" ).checkboxradio();
        }
    });

Comment: Are both requests, (the POST and the GET) from a jQuery ajax call in the same web page?  Or are the two in different web pages?  Are they both in the same domain?

Comment: yes it is, both requests from ajax call

Comment: Two ajax requests from the same web page?  Or in different web pages?  Do the web pages have the same domain as the Ajax call is going to or is at least one of these a cross origin ajax call?

Comment: two ajax request from same web page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228027/discussion-between-sports-highlights-and-jfriend00).

Comment: I don't know.  I'd say to look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger and look at exactly what headers are sent and received back with each request to see if the session cookie is getting received and/or getting sent back with the second request.